# BluetoothGatt: onClientConnParamsChanged()

Tags: android, bluetooth-lowenergy

I am developing an Android App that communicates with a BLE Peripheral. I am able to enable the notifications and receive data from the BLE Peripheral. However, a few seconds later, I receive the following message on my Android Terminal in Android Studio and the Notifications stop.

I noticed that Android phone is still connected to the BLE Peripheral as Status = 0, but after the BLE Connection Interval Change = 156, the Notifications stop.

Has anyone encountered a similar problem? I am using the BluetoothLEGatt example from Android Studio.

Thanks
Hani Abidi

```
D/BluetoothGatt: onClientConnParamsChanged() - Device=80:EA:CA:00:A8:77 interval=156 status=0enter code here
```

Comment: Hi, I'm facing the same issue. Have you solved it?

Comment: Same issue here. Anyone who solves it, please publish the solution

Comment: Did anyone ever wind up solving this issue?  I've been pulling my hair out trying to figure out how to fix this.  What I'm guessing is that the phone is deciding to negotiate the BLE connection interval right in the middle of a connection / data transmission, which screws the whole thing up.  I'm running Android 6.0.1 on an old Note 4 and I pretty reliably see this problem.  Even trying to force the connection interval negotiation doesn't appear to do anything to eliminate the problem.

Comment: Seeing the same issue here.  I initially get an `interval=6 status=0`, then if i don't request high priority it updates to `interval=36` otherwise it updates to `interval=12 status=0` during connection process.  In either case after awhile it updates again back to `interval=6 status=0` and interrupts communication. This is a major issue for us because if communication is interrupted for to long the peripheral drops the connection. :(

Answer (score 0):

So I ran into this issue as well and although I don't 100% know the exact cause, I can at least relay how I "fixed" the problem and my experiences.

So I'm using a Samsung Galaxy Note 4 running 6.0.1 and using RxAndroidBle to ease the pain of having to deal with BLE on Android.  My application connects to a PSoC4 BLE microprocessor and immediately does a back and forth data transfer with said microprocessor.  What I was seeing was similar to the OP: more often than not the back and forth transmission would just stop dead in its tracks with the following messages:

```
03-15 16:06:39.989 27793-28784/application D/BluetoothGatt: onClientConnParamsChanged() - Device=00:A0:50:65:24:91 interval=6 status=0
03-15 16:06:40.289 6292-6754/? D/BtGatt.GattService: onClientConnParamsChanged() - clientIf=7 address=00:A0:50:65:24:91, interval=39status=0
03-15 16:06:40.289 27793-28561/application D/BluetoothGatt: onClientConnParamsChanged() - Device=00:A0:50:65:24:91 interval=39 status=0
03-15 16:06:54.989 6292-6754/? D/BtGatt.GattService: onClientConnParamsChanged() - clientIf=7 address=00:A0:50:65:24:91, interval=6status=0
03-15 16:06:54.989 27793-27823/application D/BluetoothGatt: onClientConnParamsChanged() - Device=00:A0:50:65:24:91 interval=6 status=0
03-15 16:06:55.259 6292-6754/? D/BtGatt.GattService: onClientConnParamsChanged() - clientIf=7 address=00:A0:50:65:24:91, interval=39status=0
03-15 16:06:55.259 27793-28784/application D/BluetoothGatt: onClientConnParamsChanged() - Device=00:A0:50:65:24:91 interval=39 status=0
```

It appeared to me at first that for some reason the phone was still negotiating the connection interval in the middle of the data transfer and, for some reason, would just completely get screwed up as a result.

Maybe this is what is happening, maybe it isn't, but what I found was the root cause of this was that I am (apparently) connecting and interfacing with my microprocessor over BLE before the BLE device scanner is completely done shutting down.

When the user taps on the table view cell to connect to the device, I was originally calling to stop subscribing to the RxAndroidBle observable that is scanning for devices, which should end the BLE scanning and then immediately launched into showing a new Activity for communicating with the PSoC4 which in turn immediately connects and starts interfacing with the microprocessor:

```
 scanSubscription.unsubscribe();
 Intent myIntent = new Intent(MainActivity.this, ConnectedActivity.class);
 myIntent.putExtra("address", testdevice.getAddress());
 myIntent.putExtra("name", testdevice.getName());
 MainActivity.this.startActivityForResult(myIntent, CONNECTED_ACTIVITY);
```

It appears, however, that simply unsubscribing from the scan subscription does not immediately end the BLE scanning so my current strategy is to wait 500 ms before starting any communications with the other device.  This is obviously not ideal - ideally you'd have a method callback when scanning actually was ceased, but I haven't figured out how to do that just yet.

Hopefully this helps someone.

Answer (score -2):

Connection parameter update is unrelated to notification subscription status. Are you saying your onCharacteristicChanged are not being called although you send notifications from the peripheral? You should check your code again. If you think you've done everything correct you should check android's hci snoop log or use a BLE sniffer to see what really happens.